# Finding the overall sum, using for loops to iterate over two dictionaries, multiplying key values

Tags: python-3.x

Just starting out learning about python3, and have come across dictionaries. A tutorial question asks the following:

Create a dictionary named weight, initialised with the following values:
"pencil": 10
"pen": 20
"paper": 4
"eraser": 80

Create another dictionary named available, initialised with the following values:
"pen": 3
"pencil": 5
"eraser": 2
"paper": 10

## Here's where I'm having difficulties though:

write code that determines the total weight of all available items (i.e. what is the overall weight of all the pens, pencils, paper, and erasers?)

I'll need to use for loops to loop over the keys to do this.

For practice getting sums, I started by getting a sum of each individual dictionary:

```
    `weight = {"pencil": 10, "pen": 20, "paper": 4, "eraser": 80}

    print("Overall weight: ", (sum(weight.values())))

    available = {"pen": 3, "pencil": 5, "eraser": 2, "paper": 10}

    print("Available items: ", (sum(available.values())))`
```

This gave me the output of each as:
Overall weight:  114 #the overall weight of one of each item
Available items:  20 #the total amount of items

This doesn't really help me answer the question though as multiplying those values will get me the wrong answer.

This is what I've got so far, but I really have no idea how to use the for loops so keep getting errors:

```
    `weight = {"pencil": 10, "pen": 20, "paper": 4, "eraser": 80}

    available = {"pencil": 5,"pen": 3, "paper": 10, "eraser": 2}

    overall_weight = 0

    # missing for loop here

    print("Overall weight: ", overall_weight)`
```

## is it something like this?

```
    `for key in weight.keys() & available.keys():
        print(weight.items()) * (available.items())
        #missing a line here
        return overall_weight`
```

Manually, I can see the overall weight should be 310. 
(5*10)+(3*20)+(10*4)+(2*80) = 310

I know the answer is probably really simple, but really not getting my head around it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you have to do.

```
total = 0
for key, value in weight.items():
    total += value * available[key]

print(total)  # 310
```

This code does require the keys to exist in both dictionaries. And will throw a key error if you try to access a key that doesn't exist. So you could check if the key exists before accessing it in available.

```
total = 0
for key, value in weight.items():
    if key in available:
        total += value * available[key]
```

You could use `.keys()` or `.items()` to get what you need when looping through the dictionary.

`.keys()` will return an iterable of the keys of the dictionary.

```
dict_keys(['pencil', 'pen', 'paper', 'eraser'])
```

`.items()` will return the key and value for each item in the dictionary. This is useful so we don't have to access the dictionary again for the item as we loop through it.

```py
for k, v in weight.items():
    print(k, v)
```

This will print:

```
pencil 10
pen 20
paper 4
eraser 80
```

Would highly recommend reading up on Dictionaries. They are powerful data structures.

[python docs on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

[real python dictionary article](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

Comment: Legend! Knew I was missing something simple, thanks Brandon! Will play around with for loops and assigning values using +=.

Comment: Glad to help. I added some more info to my answer as well as some links that I would recommend reading on Dictionaries.